# Как заставить пустые элементы во флекс контейнере растянуться на всю ширину страницы родительского контейнера?

Tags: css3, html5

Есть родительский контейнер шириной 1920пикселей к примеру. Как сделать так, чтобы блоки без контента в main контейнере равномерно растягивались на всю его ширину?

```
<div class="main" style="width: 1920px; display: flex;">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно для flex-элементов задать `flex-grow: 1;`